# Expression of type 'String' does not match the field 'expression' on If Condition in ADFv2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm adding an If Condition to my ADFv2 Pipeline based on the output of an activity.  I'm simply checking if a file is downloaded and if so I want to load the table with the downloaded file.

My Expression looks like this:

```
@{equals(activity('RunFunction').output.files[1].Downloaded,true)}
```

And I'm getting the following warning:

```
Expression of type 'String' does not match the field 'expression'
```

How do I update my code to remove this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you have to add `{ }` in your expression? Please remove it,`@equals(A,B)` is correct format.

```
@equals(activity('Azure Function1').output.files[1].Downloaded,true)
```

Comment: I added {} from examples.  Still learning the syntax, so didn't realize they were not needed.